# Remove empty strings from a list except 1st one in Python

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, custom-lists

I am trying to remove empty strings from a list except the 1st element. I have this code -

```
my_list = ['', 'CHANGE_TO(1)', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', '1', '']
while("" in my_list[1:]) :
  my_list.remove("")
print(my_list)
```

But I am not getting the desires result. It's still removing the 1st element. The result I am looking for is -

```
['', 'CHANGE_TO(1)', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', '1']
```

But I am getting -

```
['CHANGE_TO(1)', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', '1']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
my_list = [my_list[0]] + [item for item in my_list[1:] if item != ""]
```

This code works by simply combining the result of the first element in the list `[my_list[0]]` with the filtered result you desire: `[item for item in my_list[1:] if item != ""]`.

The problem is that `.remove` will remove the first element from the list despite your `while` statement.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do something like this

enumerates() gets both the element and the index in a for loop.

```py
for i,e in enumerate(my_list):
    if e == '' and i != 0:
        my_list.pop(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
my_list = ['', 'CHANGE_TO(1)', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', '1', '']
out = [el for i, el in enumerate(my_list) if i == 0 or el]
print(out)
```

```
['', 'CHANGE_TO(1)', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', '1']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `enumerate()` to get the index: Avoid removing index 0

```py
my_list = ['', 'CHANGE_TO(1)', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', '1', '']
my_list = [
    element 
    for index, element in enumerate(my_list)
    if index > 0 and element != ""
]
```